# How to get "add to homescreen" banner to display on mobile browsers for my PWA?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have been trying to get a very basic PWA that plays with an api to work.

While the PWA **works as expected on my laptop** ( including working offline when added to homescreen), 
**no install/add to homescreen prompts/banners are seen on mobile**.

The app does not work offline either,on  mobile

**This is the service worker code :**

```js
const cacheName = 'news';

const staticAssets = [
  './',
  './app.js',
  './styles.css',
  './fallback.json',
];

self.addEventListener('install', async function () {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const request = event.request;
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  if (url.origin === location.origin) {
    event.respondWith(cacheFirst(request));
  } else {
    event.respondWith(networkFirst(request));
  }
});

async function cacheFirst(request) {
  const cachedResponse = await caches.match(request);
  return cachedResponse || fetch(request);
}

async function networkFirst(request) {
  const dynamicCache = await caches.open('news-dynamic');
  try {
    const networkResponse = await fetch(request);
    dynamicCache.put(request, networkResponse.clone());
    return networkResponse;
  } catch (err) {
    const cachedResponse = await dynamicCache.match(request);
    return cachedResponse || await caches.match('./fallback.json');
  }
}
```

**This is the manifest.json file :**

```js
{
  "name": "News",
  "short_name": "News",
  "theme_color": "#2196f3",
  "background_color": "#2196f3",
  "display": "standalone",
  "Scope": "/",
  "start_url": ".",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

Any idea on how to get it to work as expected on mobile?

Comment: Did you run your application against [lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/)?

Comment: @adelura When I audit the heroku hosted version I get an audit error: navigationStart was not found on the trace.
However when I run on my xampp , I do not see this error

Comment: If your scope is "/", why are you listing all the assets starting with a dot? Why not leave it out? This, of course, shouldn't have any reason to change anything, but you really shouldn't need the dot in there. Also: in your manifest.json, write scope with lowercase S and if your start_url is the index, use "/" instead of ".".

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this issue on this [github forum](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/2394). One of the suggested solution was to disable Adblock.

> Confirmed, it works if I tell Adblock not to run on the page.